# How to free pointer without freeing contents? An aux variable

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, binary-search-tree, free

I'm trying to tackle memory leaks more and more in my endeavor to learn this language.. 
The program I'm working on is a Binary Search Tree, the tree's root is always located at `tree->root->l`. Now if I do this...

```
BSTNode *search(BSTree *tree ,Item elem)
{
    BSTNode* aux;
    aux = tree->root->l;

    /*
    *    BSTNode not found.
    *
    */    
    if(notFound)
    {
         free(aux);
         free(found)
         return NULL;
    }
 // . . . . . .
}
```

will it also dealocate `tree->root->l`? how do I avoid it if so?

Comment: Why do you need to free the memory that `aux` points to?

Comment: considering `aux = tree->root->l`, yes it will free that because you are specifically telling it to.  To avoid it, don't `free(aux);`.

Comment: I don't know a lot about how free() works, but I had a hunch that this wouldn't be okay because it'll free the root - after looking at some `destroyTree` functions.

Comment: I had the idea that you need to free all variables when youre done with them. this one was just used to search..

Comment: You only free that which is allocated through `malloc` or `realloc` when you are done with them.  Everything else takes care of itself when it leaves scope.

Comment: Wait, why the heck is the root located in `tree->root->l` instead of `tree->root`? That’s a mistake, rethink your logic.

Comment: I know it's a weird quirk and just adds redundancy but this is how *we* are supposed to do it here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer itself is in automatic storage, which means you don't have to worry about allocating it or freeing it. As such, it's not the *pointer* you need to be worried about, but the *memory* addressed by the pointer. This is where `free` comes into play. `free` doesn't free the pointer, but the memory addressed by the pointer.

> *will it also dealocate `tree->root->l`?*

It will deallocate the memory to which both `aux` and `tree->root->l` point.

The memory in question is still being used by the tree, so it shouldn't be freed at this time.

> *how do I avoid it if so?*

Remove `free(aux);`.

> *Does this mean that if I leave variables like this it wouldn't cause a memory leak or unnecessarily used recourse?*

Correct. The question you need to ask yourself is "is the memory addressed by this pointer still being used?" If the answer is yes, don't free it. If the answer is no, free it.

Comment: Does this mean that if I leave variables like this it wouldn't cause a memory leak or  unnecessarily used recourse? so it will show as many `allocs` as there are `free's` in the memcheck

Comment: Again, the *variable* (*pointer*) will be freed automatically, so stop talking about the *variable* (*pointer*). What you have to worry about isn't the variable, but memory you allocate using `malloc` and similar. The memory in question is still being used by the tree, so not freeing it is a good thing! Another way of looking at it is that each `malloc` should have exactly one corresponding `free` at some point, and you didn't `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `tree->root->l` will be deallocated, because `aux` is pointing at the same memory. You have two pointers pointing to the same memory location. Passing either pointer to `free()` will deallocate the memory that both of them point at.

You avoid it by not passing a pointer to free that is pointing at a memory location you don't want freed.

It sounds like you're asking how to use `aux` to point at something else without freeing `tree->root->l`. To do that, you can just reassign `aux`:

```
aux = some_other_pointer;
```

There is no need to free anything as long as you retain a pointer *somewhere* that still points at memory you will need to free later.

From your comments: "I had the idea that you need to free all variables when youre done with them." This is almost correct. You have to free all *dynamically allocated* memory. You don't need to attempt to free anything that you didn't allocate with a call to `malloc`, so there's no need to call `free` on `aux`. You'll need to call `free` on every element in the binary tree at some point, but you still have the `root` pointer to track all that, and can clean it up at the end of the program or when you no longer need the tree.